# Binding Validation.HasError property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, binding

I am currently implementing a `ValidationRule` to check if some invalid character are in a TextBox. I am happy that setting the class I have implemented that inherits `ValidationRule` on my TextBox sets it in red when such characters are found, but I would also like to use the `Validation.HasError` property or the Validation.Errors property to pop a messagebox telling the user that there are errors in the various textboxes in the page.

Is there a way to bind a property in my `ViewModel` to the *`Validation.HasError`* and/or to the Validation.Errors properties in order for me to have access to them in my ViewModel?

Here is my error style for the TextBox:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorValidationTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type pres:OneTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    FontSize="12pt"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner, 
                           Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="MyAdorner"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is how I declare my TextBox (OneTextBox encapsulates the regular WPF TextBox) in my XAML:

```
<pres:OneTextBox Watermark="Name..." Margin="85,12,0,0" Style="{StaticResource ErrorValidationTextBox}"
                 AcceptsReturn="False" MaxLines="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" >
    <pres:OneTextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="InterfaceSpecification.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">                    
            <Binding.ValidationRules>                       
                <interfaceSpecsModule:NoInvalidCharsRule/>                        
            </Binding.ValidationRules>                    
        </Binding>               
    </pres:OneTextBox.Text>        
</pres:OneTextBox>
```

Comment: Just curious: Are you intentionally spreading your validation logic across view AND viewmodel?

Comment: @AndreasH. Yes, as with my validation rule, the only thing that happens is that the border of my TextBox becomes red. It does not prevent the user from inputting further characters (even though when there is an invalid character the Name property stops being updated) or it doesn't prevent him from creating an InterfaceSpecification with that name. I could bind the Validation.HasError on the "submit" button of my form, but I am using a custom framework and do not have access to that button (as it is private inside the form control, unfortunately).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Validation.HasError` is *readonly* property, therefore `Binding` will not work with this property. This can be seen in [`ILSpy`](http://ilspy.net):

```
public virtual bool HasError
{
    get
    {
        return this._validationError != null;
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you should see a great [`article`](http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/forwarding-the-result-of-wpf-validation-in-mvvm/) which provides a solution in the form of use *attached* dependency properties, there you will see a detailed explanation of the example.

Below is a full example from this article, I just translated it under `C#`, the original language is `VB.NET`:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window x:Class="HasErrorTestValidation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HasErrorTestValidation"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TestData />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="TestTextBox" 
                 local:ProtocolSettingsLayout.MVVMHasError="{Binding Path=HasError}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="TestText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <local:OnlyNumbersValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="HasError" StringFormat="HasError is {0}"/>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Path="(Validation.HasError)" ElementName="TestTextBox" StringFormat="Validation.HasError is {0}"/>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

#region Model

public class TestData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasError = false;

    public bool HasError
    {
        get
        {
            return _hasError;
        }

        set
        {
            _hasError = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HasError");
        }
    }

    private string _testText = "0";

    public string TestText
    {
        get
        {
            return _testText;
        }

        set
        {
            _testText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TestText");
        }
    }

    #region PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string sProp)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sProp));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

#endregion

#region ValidationRule

public class OnlyNumbersValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var result = new ValidationResult(true, null);

        string NumberPattern = @"^[0-9-]+$";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(NumberPattern);

        if (rgx.IsMatch(value.ToString()) == false)
        {
            result = new ValidationResult(false, "Must be only numbers");
        }

        return result;
    }
}

#endregion

public class ProtocolSettingsLayout
{       
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MVVMHasErrorProperty= DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MVVMHasError", 
                                                                    typeof(bool),
                                                                    typeof(ProtocolSettingsLayout),
                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
                                                                                                  FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                                                  null,
                                                                                                  CoerceMVVMHasError));

    public static bool GetMVVMHasError(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(MVVMHasErrorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetMVVMHasError(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MVVMHasErrorProperty, value);
    }

    private static object CoerceMVVMHasError(DependencyObject d,Object baseValue)
    {
        bool ret = (bool)baseValue;

        if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d,MVVMHasErrorProperty))
        {
            if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d)==null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Validation.HasErrorProperty, d.GetType());
                desc.AddValueChanged(d,OnHasErrorChanged);
                SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, desc);
                ret = System.Windows.Controls.Validation.GetHasError(d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d)!=null)
            {
                DependencyPropertyDescriptor desc= GetHasErrorDescriptor(d);
                desc.RemoveValueChanged(d, OnHasErrorChanged);
                SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, null);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorDescriptorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasErrorDescriptor", 
                                                                            typeof(DependencyPropertyDescriptor),
                                                                            typeof(ProtocolSettingsLayout));

    private static DependencyPropertyDescriptor GetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d)
    {
        var ret = d.GetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty);
        return ret as DependencyPropertyDescriptor;
    }

    private static void OnHasErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject d = sender as DependencyObject;

        if (d != null)
        {
            d.SetValue(MVVMHasErrorProperty, d.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty));
        }
    }

   private static void SetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyDescriptor value)
   {
        var ret = d.GetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty);
        d.SetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty, value);
    }
}
```

As an alternative to the use of `ValidationRule`, in MVVM style you can try to implement [`IDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) Interface. For more info see this:

[Enforcing Complex Business Data Rules with WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714593.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As for IDataErrorInfo, I have looked into it a bit, but to my understanding, the end result is the same as a ValidationRule: it only shows in the view to the user that there is an error, it does not prevent the user from continuing with the flow of the program until that error is resolved. And, as mentioned in a comment I made in my question, I am using a custom framework which doesn't give me access to the "submit" button of my form, so I cannot disable that button myself when there is an error unfortunately (that is why I am trying to find a workaround).

Comment: @choub890: You could prevent the value of the viewmodel being set in the setter if the new value is not valid, but raising INotifyPropertyChanged event, so the textbox is updated with the old value, which hasnt changed.

Comment: This works fine with normal xaml, but in a custom control when I try to bind the attached property using a template binding, the BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d,MVVMHasErrorProperty) call in CoerceMVVMHasError(...) returns false, so the callback never gets installed. Any ideas for how to make this work in a custom control?

Comment: @Brian Stewart: Can you give a concrete example of the non-working project? How will the time, I'll see it.

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev: I added an example as an answer to this question that shows your technique working with standard XAML, and not working when that XAML is placed within a custom control. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the binding mode one way to source meant exactly for these read only properties

Comment: local:ProtocolSettingsLayout.MVVMHasError="{Binding Path=HasError}" is showing error that says MVVMHasError not found in type ProtocolSettingsLayout. But I correctly designed the class and when I click to go to definition it is taking to the right place. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

all perfect work set `NotifyOnValidationError="True"` on binding;
(or maybe with binding group also possible)

then use

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=tbPeriod, Path=(Validation.HasError)}"
```

sample with one textBox:

`<val:RangeRule`can be changed to ms sample agerangerule etc

```
<TextBox MaxLength="5" x:Name="tbPeriod" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="162" Margin="10,10,0,0" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxInError}">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="ReportPeriod" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <val:RangeRule Min="70" Max="5000" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

In response to Anatoliy's request for an example of a non-working project:

### Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAttachedPropertyValidationError">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxCustomControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Content="Enter a numeric value:" />
                        <TextBox 
                            Grid.Row ="0" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            local:HasErrorUtility.HasError="{Binding NumericPropHasError, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Text="{Binding NumericProp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Content="Value entered:" />
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="1" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding NumericProp}" />
                        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="2" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding NumericPropHasError, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            Foreground="Red" 
                            Content="Not a numeric value" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

### TextBoxCustomControl.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestAttachedPropertyValidationError
{
    public class TextBoxCustomControl : Control
    {
        static TextBoxCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextBoxCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextBoxCustomControl)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericPropProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NumericProp", typeof (int), typeof (TextBoxCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

        public int NumericProp
        {
            get { return (int) GetValue(NumericPropProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumericPropProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericPropHasErrorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NumericPropHasError", typeof (bool), typeof (TextBoxCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool NumericPropHasError
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(NumericPropHasErrorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NumericPropHasErrorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

### HasErrorUtility.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestAttachedPropertyValidationError
{
    class HasErrorUtility
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasError",
                                                                        typeof(bool),
                                                                        typeof(HasErrorUtility),
                                                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                                                                                                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                                                                                                      null,
                                                                                                      CoerceHasError));

        public static bool GetHasError(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(HasErrorProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHasError(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value);
        }

        private static object CoerceHasError(DependencyObject d, Object baseValue)
        {
            var ret = (bool)baseValue;
            if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(d, HasErrorProperty))
            {
                if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) == null)
                {
                    var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Validation.HasErrorProperty, d.GetType());
                    desc.AddValueChanged(d, OnHasErrorChanged);
                    SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, desc);
                    ret = Validation.GetHasError(d);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (GetHasErrorDescriptor(d) != null)
                {
                    var desc = GetHasErrorDescriptor(d);
                    desc.RemoveValueChanged(d, OnHasErrorChanged);
                    SetHasErrorDescriptor(d, null);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        private static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorDescriptorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasErrorDescriptor",
                                                                                typeof(DependencyPropertyDescriptor),
                                                                                typeof(HasErrorUtility));

        private static DependencyPropertyDescriptor GetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d)
        {
            var ret = d.GetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty);
            return ret as DependencyPropertyDescriptor;
        }

        private static void SetHasErrorDescriptor(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyDescriptor value)
        {
            d.SetValue(HasErrorDescriptorProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnHasErrorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var d = sender as DependencyObject;

            if (d != null)
            {
                d.SetValue(HasErrorProperty, d.GetValue(Validation.HasErrorProperty));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

### ViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace TestAttachedPropertyValidationError
{
    public class ViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private int _vmNumericProp;
        private bool _vmNumericPropHasError;

        public int VmNumericProp
        {
            get { return _vmNumericProp; }
            set
            {
                _vmNumericProp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool VmNumericPropHasError
        {
            get { return _vmNumericPropHasError; }
            set
            {
                _vmNumericPropHasError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestAttachedPropertyValidationError.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAttachedPropertyValidationError"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="VM1"/>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="VM2"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label Content="Custom Control...}"></Label>
    <local:TextBoxCustomControl 
        Margin="10" 
        DataContext="{StaticResource VM1}"
        NumericProp="{Binding VmNumericProp}"
        NumericPropHasError="{Binding VmNumericPropHasError}"/>
    <Label Content="Regular XAML...}" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
    <Grid 
        Margin="10"
        DataContext="{StaticResource VM2}"
        >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Content="Enter a numeric value:" />
        <TextBox 
                            Grid.Row ="0" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            local:HasErrorUtility.HasError="{Binding VmNumericPropHasError, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Text="{Binding VmNumericProp, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="1" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Content="Value entered:" />
        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="1" 
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            Content="{Binding VmNumericProp}" />
        <Label 
                            Grid.Row ="2" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                            Visibility="{Binding VmNumericPropHasError, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            Foreground="Red" 
                            Content="Not a numeric value" />
    </Grid>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I do not quite understand your example.`Validation.HasError` primarily needed when using `ValidationRule`,in your example it is not. In addition, in my computer (Windows 7), both examples return false in the *Coerce()* function. The meaning of this example that `Binding` is not working in `Validation.HasError` by default, because this property is not a dependency property, and this example compensates this disadvantage.Besides,in your custom control you're simply assigning a bool value to a dependency property -> in this situation Coerce function will not normally be called in HasErrorUtility.