# Handle Convert exception with INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have a textbox in my View where the user may type in a TCP Port value.
The textbox binds directly to the Model's Port property (of type Int32) since the ViewModel provides the complete model for binding. The Model is inheriting from ObservableObject so binding to it directly is working well.

I use INotifyDataErrorInfo in my Model, and the Port property validates the value in the property setter (it has to be greater than 0).

I have a button in my view that binds to the Model's HasError() method and sets its IsEnabled state based on the boolean return value from HasError()

Now to the problem, if the user type in "Hello world" there would be an exception thrown by the WPF binding engine. In such case the property setter is never executed hence the HasError() never changes to true for such invalid input.

I could of course set "ValidatesOnExceptions=True" for the textbox in the View to at least have the textbox to show its validation error template in this case, but still the button would not be disabled.

Question, what is the recommended solution how to handle these cases where automatic conversion fails such that the ViewModel / Model's validation is never executed?

I would be okay with a solution where the Validation executes on the textbox string instead of on the Int32 type, executing before the failing automatic type conversion to Int32 is performed by the WPF binding engine.

A solution I really want to avoid is to have my ViewModel / Model property to always be of type string, validate the string in the setter then try to manually cast it to the correct type (Int32 in this case). There must be a better solution avoiding all such manual casts.

When using ValidationRules one could tell the Validation engine to execute the  ValidationRule before the automatic conversion. What I am really looking for is a way to do execute the INotifyDataErrorInfo validation also before the automatic cast is done.

Comment: What is the recommended solution to what problem? Obviously you view model cannot handle this kind of exceptions because it's never involved. The exception that occurs when you try to convert the string to an int is already handled for you by the framework so what is your actual question?

Comment: Yes, how can I execute the validation before the automatic conversion.
I updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Use a ValidationRule in the view. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulties you're experiencing are exemplary of why you should *not* be binding directly to your model from your view.  The whole point of the view model is to translate presentation concerns back and forth between the view and broker that interaction with the underlying model.

For instance: if your view provides a string for the port, then the view model would validate that and convert it (if valid) to an integer for the model or else notify the view of invalid input through whatever error notification mechanism.

Comment: Okay, so no way to get around this without all such manual translations between types. Seems like a lot of unnecessary code when the Model is already supporting the binding (ObservableObject)

Comment: You should not change the type of your view model properties from `int` to `string` if that's what you are thinking. A view model is not responsible for handling a view's way to set its properties.

Comment: @mm8 please explain, if I dont change the VM property type to string the validation performed in the VM property will never be executed. I now use string in the VM and then cast it to Int before setting the value in the model. But it also has a drawback. If the model changes the Int value the binding would not update unless I explicitly subscribe to model's events in the VM. Not a clean way to solve it but seems to be no better way.

Comment: @Johan: You may bind to the Validation.HasError property using an attached behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827437/binding-validation-haserror-property-in-mvvm

Answer (score 0):

An `int` property cannot be set to anything else than an `int` value. When you try to set it to "Hello world", the binding engine catches the exception and takes care of it for you.

If you want to perform the validation yourself, or customize the error message, you could define a custom `ValidationRule` and set its `ValidationStep` property to `RawProposedValue` in order for it to be applied before the value conversion occurs:

```
public class StringToIntValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid integer value.");
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Age" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringToIntValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Note that this kind of validation or customization doesn't involve the view model. It's a framework/view/control thing.

Comment: Yes I am aware of ValidationRule. Problem is as you say the VM is not involved and I want other Elements (buttons for example) to be disabled if there are any validation errors in the view and also based on some state of other objects. I dont see a good way to solve that using ValidationRule.

Comment: At the moment the button command is binding to a RelayCommand. And the relaycommand sets the enabled state of the button based on INotifyDataErrorInfo's HasError and the states of the other objects.