# Xamarin update viewmodel with command

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

currently I don't know how to solve my problem. I am writing an app with xamarin.forms.

I have a view which contains the userprofile of the user. For example there is a entry with the username. The field is binded in the twoway mode to the viewmodel:

```
<Entry x:Name="givennameSurname"  Text="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The whole userprofile contains some fields which are validated with a behavior:

```
<behaviors:TelNumBehavior x:Name="NumValidatorUser" IsValid="{Binding Source={x:Reference root}, Path=BindingContext.UserTelNumBehavior, Mode=TwoWay }"></behaviors:TelNumBehavior>
```

The isValid property is also binded to the viewmodel.

What I want to achieve? I want, that if one of the behaviors validate the input to false, that the userprofile can not be updated.

So I wanted to create a command on a button. The button has an canExecute method: this method checks the booleans in the viewmodel if they all are true or false. If true, I want to force a refresh of the data of viewmodel from the view. I use that canExecute also to prevent unwanted changes, if the UI is in the state, that some input is wrong:

```
    public string FullName
    {
        get => profile.GivenName;
        set
        {
            if (CanSave())
            {
                    profile.GivenName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the problem?
I change an input with a behavior, so that the behavior says the input is wrong. Then I edit the username. Then I change the input of the wrong-behavior to true. Now the input of the username does not refresh in the viewmodel. I want to refresh it with the command, but I don't know how to force a refresh from the view to the viewmodel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin View with ViewModel and Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567801/xamarin-view-with-viewmodel-and-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to write what property  you changing in your getter and setter so:

```
OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
```