# Binding to Combobox Validation.Errors in control template

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Combobox With a custom `ControlTemplate` and I want to change the `BackgroundColor` based on the Controls `Validation.Errors` property which is a WPF concept on validation.

I've decided to this by using a `Trigger`. My `ControlTemplate.Triggers` is defined like this

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource validationRequiredError}}" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="DeepPink"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

My Combobox looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Margin="0" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                    IsEditable="False"
                    Style="{StaticResource ValidateableCombobox}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Lists.EstimatedDurations}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Model.EstimatedDuration, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SelectedValuePath="Duration"/>
```

I've sure that the validation defined in `FluentValidation` is run and added to the `Errors` Collection, but the converter specified in the Trigger is never run.

I have also checked the Output to verify Binding Errors, but none are shown. Do I need to add something special to my `ControlTemplate` to make sure the `Errors` property are bound correctly? Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Your triggers don't work because 'Validation.Errors' is a read-only attached property. You can't use bindings on a read-only dependency or read-only attached property. The recommended way is to let your view model implement 'INotifyDataErrorInfo' and create a validation error template that meets your design requirements. See my answer on how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023337/how-to-disable-button-on-validation-error/54025419#54025419

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode I've decided an alternative apporach and setting the Control template in the style.triggers.